# Can app send email without letting the user know the email address?

Tags: ios, iphone, email

I wish to receive some comments from the users via email from my iOS app, but I don't want my email address to be exposed to the users. Is it possible to implement such mechanism?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It isn't possible with the default apple frameworks

you can do one of the following

1. EITHER add a third party framework (library) to your iOS app that adds email sending capabilities to your app

   -- BUT even with that you won't be able to access the system email account (which is outside your sandbox)

   ==> likely not what you want
2. OR you do a direct HTTP/FTP (whatever protocol) call to your server and have a script running there that does the sending itself for your app

Answer (score 2):

> Q. Can app send email without letting the user know the email address?
>
> A. No,its not possible to send email in iOS system without letting know email id of sender.

But if you want to develop system where you want to receive feedback,I would suggest you use `Parse SDK`,where you can simply send user's reply via rest service to parse server,And would like to make simple web or android app to retrieve those feedbacks directly on your device without exposing your Email ID

Answer (score 0):

It may possible only by creating own server-side mail functions. You have to send request with all parameter, which you can set, like email, body of mail, subject, etc. and server will send mail from your side..

This way you can send mail without `MFMailComposeViewController`.

Without this, Sending emails programmatically, without user intervention, from an iOS application, cannot be implemented using any of the Apple frameworks. It could be possible in a jailbroken phone but then it would never see the inside of App Store.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, You can use `SMTP` thru send mail.

For that here one of the library thru we can able to send email with knowing of user.For that refer this [skpsmtpmessage](https://github.com/jetseven/skpsmtpmessage) library.

And more detail code goes here once insert library code into project then follow below setps.

In .h file use following code

```
    #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
    #import "SKPSMTPMessage.h"
    @interface mailTransferViewController : UIViewController &lt;SKPSMTPMessageDelegate&gt;{
        IBOutlet UITextField *emailField;
    }
    - (IBAction)sendMessageInBack:(id)anObject;
    @end
```

And .m file contain following code.

```
- (IBAction)sendMessageInBack:(id)anObject{

    NSLog(@"Start Sending");
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *writableDBPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"sample.pdf"];
    NSData *dataObj = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:writableDBPath];
    SKPSMTPMessage *testMsg = [[SKPSMTPMessage alloc] init];
    testMsg.fromEmail = @"Yours mail ids";
    testMsg.toEmail = emailField.text;//sender mail id
    testMsg.relayHost = @"smtp.gmail.com";
    testMsg.requiresAuth = YES;
    testMsg.login = @"Your mail ids";
    testMsg.pass = @"Mail id password";
    testMsg.subject = @"Test application ";
    testMsg.wantsSecure = YES; // smtp.gmail.com doesn't work without TLS!
    // Only do this for self-signed certs!
    // testMsg.validateSSLChain = NO;
    testMsg.delegate = self;
    NSDictionary *plainPart = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"text/plain",kSKPSMTPPartContentTypeKey,@"Some text to include in body",kSKPSMTPPartMessageKey,@"8bit",kSKPSMTPPartContentTransferEncodingKey,nil];
    //Logic for attach file.
//  NSDictionary *vcfPart = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"text/directory;\r\n\tx-unix-mode=0644;\r\n\tname=\"sample.pdf\"",kSKPSMTPPartContentTypeKey,@"attachment;\r\n\tfilename=\"sample.pdf\"",kSKPSMTPPartContentDispositionKey,[dataObj encodeBase64ForData],kSKPSMTPPartMessageKey,@"base64",kSKPSMTPPartContentTransferEncodingKey,nil];
//    NSLog(@"%@",vcfPart);
//  testMsg.parts = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:plainPart,vcfPart,nil];
//    testMsg.parts = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:plainPart,vcfPart,nil];

    testMsg.parts = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:plainPart,nil];
    [testMsg send];
}
```

I think your problem has been resolve by this solution.

Answer (score -1):

1: Add MessageUI framework:

Click on the project
Select "Build Phases"
Expand "Link Binary With Libraries"
Click "+" and type "Message" to find "MessageUI" framework, then add.

2: In current view controller add import and implement a protocol:

```
         #import <MessageUI/MessageUI.h> 
    #import <MessageUI/MFMailComposeViewController.h> 
    @interface MyViewController : UIViewController<MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate>








 -(void)sendEmail {
            // From within your active view controller
            if([MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail]) {
                MFMailComposeViewController *mailCont = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
                mailCont.mailComposeDelegate = self;        // Required to invoke mailComposeController when send

                [mailCont setSubject:@"Email subject"];
                [mailCont setToRecipients:[NSArray arrayWithObject:@"myFriends@email.com"]];
                [mailCont setMessageBody:@"Email message" isHTML:NO];

                [self presentViewController:mailCont animated:YES completion:nil];
            }
        }

        - (void)mailComposeController:(MFMailComposeViewController*)controller didFinishWithResult:(MFMailComposeResult)result error:(NSError*)error {
            [controller dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
    }
```

Comment: Give your email-ID at <myFriends@email.com>